# set div at the bottom of parent div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a *div* (hover) that overlaps a image on hovering, it works perfectly until now. Inside that div I have a text (title) and another div (details). The height of the `.hover div`is variable, and I need to put the `details div` in the bottom of the parent div (`.hover`) and the title at the top. Next is the HTML structure:

```
<div class="grid-item">
        <img class="Movieimg" src="img.jpg">

        <div class="hover">
            <div class="title">The title</div>

            <div class="details pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs nzbdetails" href="" target="_self"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Details">
                    <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs getnzb" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Get NZB">
                    <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the current CSS is this one:

```
.grid-item img{
        width:150px;
    }
.grid-item {
        position:relative;
 }
 img:hover{
        cursor: pointer;
        cursor: hand;
        filter:blur(5px);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
}

.grid-item .hover {
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        width: 100%;
 }

 .details a{
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        margin-top: 80%;
 }

.grid-item:hover .hover {
    display:block;
    height: 100%;
}
 .title{
    text-align:center;
    width:calc(100% - 10px);
    position:absolute;
    left:5px;
}
```

Also, I'm using **Bootstrap 3**, so maybe there's a class to achieve this?

Comment: Your code is [`not complete`](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/tmo110w2/). Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your question wasn't quite clear to me but I think this is what you wan't to achieve. I have just used the bootstrap grid-layout to get the proper grid structure. I found some of your css is unnecessary so removed these blocks as you can achieve the desired effect without using the css rather bootstrap grid system should be sufficient.

**The removed css blocks**

```
.title{
text-align:center;
width:calc(100% - 10px);
position:absolute;
left:5px;
}

 margin-top: 80%;
 .grid-item img{
    width:150px;// inserted class="img-responsive in place of it
}
```

**Working code snippet**

```css
.grid-item {
        position:relative;
 }
 img:hover{
        cursor: pointer;
        cursor: hand;
        filter:blur(5px);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
}

.grid-item .hover {
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
 }

 .details a{
        margin-bottom: 5px;
 }

.grid-item:hover .hover {
    display:block;
    height: 100%;
}
 /*.title{
    text-align:center;
    width:calc(100% - 10px);
    position:absolute;
    left:5px;
}*/
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
           
          </head>
          <body>
          <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="grid-item">
          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <img class="Movieimg img-responsive" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/19/15/46/dog-1210559_960_720.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="hover col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-9 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-3">
        <div class="row">
           <div class=" col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="title">The title</div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="details col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs nzbdetails" href="" target="_self"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Details">
                    <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs getnzb" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Get NZB">
                    <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
            </div>
</div>
</div>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```